# Wordpress Multisite plugin

Tags: wordpress, domain-mapping

For installation Wordpress Multisite is this plugin required in version 5.x or not -- [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)

Or in Wordpress version 5.x the feature of installing Wordpress Multisite is already built up inside the code?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress Multisite plugin required in version 5.x. but you have to installed the lastest version of WordPress. Then, you can try to test on new version of WordPress.